# Differential in Lie groups

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to make sense of the Lie group machinery and relate it to the calculus.

Suppose that $\psi(t)=\phi(s)\phi(t), s, t \in I$.

Where $\phi(t)$ is a one-parameter subgroup of the Lie group $G$ and $I$ is an open interval containing $0$.

So we have $\phi: \mathbb R \to G$ (a smooth homomorphism).

Now **using simple calculus** we can find the differential of $\psi(t)$, treating it as a matrix, here each element is a function of $t$. Using the above, and for a fixed $s$, we can say as usual in the calculus $d\psi(t)=\phi(s)d\phi(t)$.

But if instead of calculus we **use the Lie group definitions** I cannot easily make sense of the differential.

Based on the definition if $ \psi(t): \mathbb R \to G, t \in \mathbb R ,\psi(t) \in G$ (assuming the group structure of the manifold) then $d\psi(t)$ is

$d\psi(t): T_t\mathbb R \to T_{\psi(t)}G$ here, by definition we have

$d\psi(t)(v)(g)=v(g \circ \psi) \in T_{\psi(t)}G, v\in T_t\mathbb R, g\in \mathcal F(G) $

Here $\mathcal F$ is the set of all smooth real-valued function on $G$. So $g: G \to \mathbb R$

Now my question is that how we can use the above definition of differential in Lie groups to say that

$d\psi(t)=\phi(s)d\phi(t)$.

or more explicitly,

$d\psi(t)(v)(g)=\phi(s)d\phi(v)(g)$

Comment: This is not MO material, but math.SE is a perfect fit, since you do not give a physical motivation (and I don't see one). I would also ask you to look carefully at the assertion $\mathrm{d}\psi(t) = \phi(s)\mathrm{d}\phi(t)$, since the differentials are *algebra-valued*, you cannot simply multiply them with a *group-valued* function. If you actually mean the adjoint action, then you should get your desired result by writing the group elements as exponentials of algebra elements and using that the tangent vectors act as derivations.

Comment: @doetoe can you add your comment here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to write $\gamma := \phi(s)$, and $L_\gamma: G\to G$ for the map $x\mapsto\gamma x$. If I understand you correctly, you are assuming that $G$ is a matrix group, and your $\phi$ is a matrix with coefficients $\phi_{ij}$ which are functions of a real parameter $t$. Then it can be checked that $\dot\psi(t)\equiv(\gamma\phi)^\cdot(t) = \gamma\dot\phi(t)$, which in your notation is $d\psi(t) = \gamma d\phi(t)$.

For the abstract definition, as @ACuriousMind remarked, you have to be careful with the notation. You are essentially asserting that $D_t(\gamma\phi) = \gamma D_t\phi$, but you have to be more careful. Our $\psi$ is the composition $L_\gamma\circ\phi$, and by the chain rule we have $D_t\psi = D_{\phi(t)}L_\gamma\circ D_t\phi$, so that what you really want to see is that in the case of matrix groups your $D_{\phi(t)}L_\gamma$ corresponds to left matrix multiplication by $\gamma$ on the Lie algebra, where its elements are represented by matrices of the same size. The most direct way to see this is essentially your same calculus computation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now make sense. @joe-johnson-126 see this.